# How to map Table Valued Functions in EF6 Code First with different column names?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, user-defined-functions

It is possible to map a table valued functions in EF6 without edmx? The problem is that the columns in the database are named differently than in the application.

My application as a simplified example.

### **Database**

The table **user** on SQL Server 2016:

```
User
Id   (int, Identity, PK)
Name (nvarchar(255)
```

The table valued function **GetUser(id)** on SQL Server 2016:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUser](@ID int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.User
    WHERE Id = @ID
);
```

### **Application**

I use the following nuget package:

```cs
Install-Package EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions
```

The related object in C#:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

The database set in my DbContext class:

```cs
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

My user configuration with column mapping:

```cs
private void ConfigureUser(EntityTypeConfiguration<User> configuration)
{
    configuration.ToTable("User");

    configuration.HasKey(user => user.Id);
    configuration.Property(user => user.Id).HasColumnName("Id").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    configuration.Property(user => user.UserName).HasColumnName("Name");
}
```

My stored procedure (TVF):

```cs
[DbFunction(nameof(ApplicationDb), "GetUser")]
    public virtual IQueryable<User> GetUser(Nullable<int> id)
    {   
        var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("ID", id) :
        new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(int));
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<User>("[GetUser](@ID)", idParameter);
    }
```

The OnModelCreating method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    if (modelBuilder == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));
    }

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new CodeFirstStoreFunctions.FunctionsConvention<MyDbContext>("dbo"));

    this.ConfigureUser(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());

    // ...
}
```

### **Problem**

My problem is the following line:

```cs
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<User>("[GetUser](@ID)", idParameter);
```

The table valued function expects a type with the properties like the table column. The correct spelling is necessary, so I need a mapping. It is an external database, so I can not change the columns in SQL Server. The project does not allow to use the edmx model.

I do not want to create the following type:

```cs
public class GetUserResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Exception: **Invalid column name 'UserName'.**

StackTrace:

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

How is it possible?

A centrales manual mapping between table column name and property name of entities would not be a problem.
Thanks

Comment: Please try with my code . I hope you will like it :)

Comment: If the column name is the same as the property name, everything works fine. But in my case the column name is *Name* and property name in my entity is *UserName*. (As a simplified example!)

Comment: ok let me try this :) I missed the main part of question :)

Comment: need to try this Complex type in model builder whihc can be used instead of the main entity class . I will try and let you know

Comment: [Old issue](https://github.com/moozzyk/CodeFirstFunctions/issues/2). Not yet resolved. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to modify your object and you cannot modify the database, but you can still modify your query. Try naming the columns in the result of the table valued function:

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<User>(
    "SELECT Id, Name AS UserName FROM [GetUser](@ID)", idParameter
);
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but somehow, apparently it doesn't - for whichever column I list first in my `SELECT` statement, I am getting the "could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly." error message.

Comment: Alternatively, if I try to map the function with `AS u` and qualify the column names in the `SELECT` statement with `u.`, I get the very curious "'Name' is not a member of type 'CodeFirstNamespace.User' in the currently loaded schemas." exception. (I'm using different types and column names here, but things are otherwise analogous.)

Comment: I think what is happening there is that the SQL query passed to `CreateQuery` is not executed verbatim. Rather than that, EF translates that SQL string into an object representation first, then generates SQL from there - hence, the mapping of the table-valued function result somehow already happens in the object representation of the `FROM` clause, not for the final result of the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score -1):

Hi it took good 30 minutes but I am able to get the result propery casted to type user. I followed the same steps as mentioned here just one change in the GetUser DBFunction . Below is my all classes and result . I hope this is what you want.

First my context class : please check getuser function I added gettype.Name function which was not present in ur code.

```
public class SampleDbContext : DbContext
        {
            public SampleDbContext()
                : base("name=SampleDBConnection")
            {
                this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
            }

            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
            public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }


            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {

                modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<SampleDbContext>("dbo"));



            }

            [DbFunction("SampleDbContext", "CustomersByZipCode")]
            public IQueryable<Customer> CustomersByZipCode(string zipCode)
            {
                var zipCodeParameter = zipCode != null ?
                    new ObjectParameter("ZipCode", zipCode) :
                    new ObjectParameter("ZipCode", typeof(string));

                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext
                    .CreateQuery<Customer>(
                        string.Format("[{0}].{1}", GetType().Name,
                            "[CustomersByZipCode](@ZipCode)"), zipCodeParameter);
            }


            [DbFunction("SampleDbContext", "GetUser")]
            public virtual IQueryable<User> GetUser(int? id)
            {
                var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ID", id) :
                new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(int));
                return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<User>(
                        string.Format("[{0}].{1}", GetType().Name,
                            "[GetUser](@ID)"), idParameter);
            }
        }
```

My EF model classes

```
        public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }

            public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        }

        public class User
        {
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Column("Name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }


        }
```

Here are my two migrations . I tested first with customer and later added user to my db context thats why I have 2 migration .

- Migration when customer is added in context

  ```
   public override void Up()
          {
              CreateTable(
                  "dbo.Customers",
                  c => new
                      {
                          Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                          Name = c.String(),
                          ZipCode = c.String(),
                      })
                  .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
              Sql(@"CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomersByZipCode](@ZipCode nchar(5)) 
              RETURNS TABLE 
              RETURN 
              SELECT [Id], [Name], [ZipCode] 
              FROM [dbo].[Customers]  
              WHERE [ZipCode] = @ZipCode");

          }

          public override void Down()
          {
              DropTable("dbo.Customers");
              Sql(@"Drop FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomersByZipCode]");

          }
  ```

  Second Migration when User is added in context

  ```
     public override void Up()
          {
              CreateTable(
                  "dbo.Users",
                  c => new
                      {
                          Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                          Name = c.String(),
                      })
                  .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
              Sql(@" CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUser](@ID int)
                  RETURNS TABLE
                  AS
                  RETURN 
                  (
                      SELECT *
                      FROM dbo.Users
                      WHERE Id = @ID
                  )");

          }

          public override void Down()
          {
              DropTable("dbo.Users");
              Sql(@" drop FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUser] ");
          }
  ```

Code and Output of in console application : I added few records in both table manually to test

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question on how to map a column with one name to a C# property with another name.